# DNS: None of the name servers responded in a timely manner

Tags: dns, server, webserver

my website can not be accessed by anyone except me, when i test it via domain checker http://mxtoolbox.com/ and i got this error:

```
DNS: None of the name servers responded in a timely manner
```

i'm not actually familiar with such problem and i don't know how to handle it. can you please help me to solve it?

this is my website if you need to check it yourself by mxtoolbox:
www.daffostore.com

many thanks

Comment: Well, the DNS configuration for the domain is messed up and/or the responsible DNS servers are down. Talk to your domain/DNS registrar/host.

Comment: can I solve it via control panel without the need to talk to the host?

Comment: I do not know since I do not know what "the control panel" is or does or where exactly the problem lies.